# Can I use Project from view while having several images for different sides?

Tags: texturing, uv

I basically was following Ian Hubert "tutorial" https://youtu.be/xWq-ZPMhai8?t=30 , where he uses this function, so he textured 4 humans from their photos, but he also managed to texture their backs somehow, which I don`t understand how to do in this mode. Would be happy for claryfying!

Comment: for the pants or shirt it's almost like the front so you won't see any difference for a far point of view, for the head he must just reduce and place the UVs over a part of the image where you have only hair

Comment: so does it mean I cant make project from view using one image and then use different view and different image while retain the part I have previously done?

Comment: yes you can, there are different techniques actually, you can use the technique he shows (put the UV over the photo), you could also properly unwrap your character mesh, give it a white image texture and use a Stencil or Clone brush to paint with the photo. If you have several points of view you can use the technique called Projection Painting as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxD0qaTFZnk

Comment: actually if you want more help, maybe share your mesh and your photo (or something close to what they are)

Comment: many thanks, I think I have got all the answers! Just one thing, when you say baking the texture it`s really baking or just saving is enough?

Comment: You need to bake if you plan to paint in Weight Paint mode to bring some corrections to the projected texture, in that case, duplicate your object, unwrap but this time with the Smart UV Project option, give it a black Image Texture, bake the original. Now you can paint over the new object, for example with the Clone brush, without affecting the original picture, which could cause problems

Comment: Understood. thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117779/discussion-between-audio-video-enthusiast-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Ian Hubert does is a bit punky, but as his characters are far away it works fine. Basically I think he projects his mesh from view, then moves the vertices in the *UV Editor* so that the UV matches as much as possible with the picture:

[image]

Then, for the sides and back, he probably unwrap this faces and put the UV islands over a part of the picture that will texture correctly this part of the body:

[image]

At the end, if you plan to paint in *Weight Paint* mode to bring some corrections to the projected texture, duplicate your object, unwrap again, but this time with the *Smart UV Project* option (with a enough margin), give it a black image texture, bake the original. Now you can paint over the new object, for example with the *Clone* brush, without affecting the original picture, which could cause problems because overlapping UVs:

[image]